# python image processing library has filters(distortion, lights) used for generate dataset

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, python-imaging-library, object-detection

I'm try to generate a **dataset used for object detection**(about **1e6** pictures). I have images of objects, and backgrounds. But I think adding some filters on objects & objects+background is good for model training. After investigation, I found I have to use those following filters:

1. distortion, including shear with curve, distortion with sphere
2. cast lights on the img.
3. other simple filter like rotate, resize, blur, noisy, color gradation...

I wonder if there is any library, which is simple to use(input args + [w, h, 4], return [w, h, 4]), natural, fast, and most of all, it can **add lights** and lens light on img and **distort** it.

Or any library that can work with python during mxnet training.

[ORG IMG1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krvZX.png)

[Distortion1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdpPt.png)

[ORG2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVv5N.png)

[Distortion2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP2H8.png)

[Lights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWHlt.png)

After observing Photoshop, I have tried to make my own filters using sphere, ellipse and para-curve formulas by PIL, opencv and scimage, However, those filters are not natural and not as good as Photoshop does.

I also tried gimp-python, but I want to use it in a pure python program and I want to process the pictures during training. Maybe speed is really important.

Comment: If you could give `photoshop` examples you tried, with the source image and the results, it would be helpfull for the readers.

Comment: thx for ur advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These blog seems a practical way of distortion: http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/imagewarp/